# Android Scroll Weighted Sum > 100%

Tags: android, android-layout

In pure XML, I am creating a list of things which requires scrolling. I have a `LinearLayout` with a weighted sum of 3 and it contains four items inside of it. Altogether the items inside of the `LinearLayout` add up to 133% of their parents' height.

Trimmed down example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_weight="1" />
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I use a `ScrollView` to bring the last item into view? Simply wrapping the `LinearLayout` in a scroller causes the layout to lose all concept of its height, causing its children's height to `wrap_content`, not stretch.

[image: Before and After ScrollView]

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can simply provide a constant height to each of the four inner views (instead of using weight), I don't believe there's any way to do what you want without resorting to Java code that adjusts the height of the inner views. This belief is based on two concepts:

First, in order to scroll, the contents of a `ScrollView` must be taller than the `ScrollView` itself. This means that you cannot use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on the `LinearLayout` and also get scrolling.

Second, `layout_weight` only distributes **excess** space among child views. In other words, this attribute only takes effect when the child views' inherent dimensions are smaller than the parent's. This means that you cannot use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` on the `LinearLayout` and also get weighted distribution of height.

That leaves setting a constant height as the only option.

If you're ok with using Java code to dynamically update the height of the child views, here's a template for doing so:

**layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#caf"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#fff"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#fca"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#afc"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final View scrollingParent = findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    scrollingParent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int childHeight = scrollingParent.getHeight() / 3;
            setHeight(R.id.one, childHeight);
            setHeight(R.id.two, childHeight);
            setHeight(R.id.three, childHeight);
            setHeight(R.id.four, childHeight);
        }
    });
}

private void setHeight(int viewId, int height) {
    View v = findViewById(viewId);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = height;
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

The `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` class and the associated `addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` call will wait until the scrolling parent is actually measured and laid out by the system, so that you have a real value for its height when you call `scrollingParent.getHeight()`. Then you just update the `LayoutParams` of each child view to have the height you want.

[image] [image]